# How to play local audio/video files in all iPhone and iPad versions from with in our PhoneGap application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, video, cordova

My requirement is to play local (bundled with the app) audio and video files  in all iPhone and iPad versions from within in the PhoneGap application.

I have tried using HTML5 audio and video tags to play local audio and video files respectively. I am able to play them in the iPhone and iPad 5.0 and 4.2.x simulators.

I am not sure if HTML5 video and audio tags are supported on which versions of iPad and iPhone iOS.

Cam you please let me know which versions support HTML5? 
If only new versions support them how can i play audio and video files on all versions from within PhoneGap application?

Thanks,
Prasanth

Comment: Have you tested this on the iPad itself? Never trust the simulator.

Comment: Thanks..I just now tested in iPad by enabling controls attribute of video tag and it is working fine. Now can you please tell me, will it work on all versions of iPhone and iPad?

Comment: It's hard to make that call without extensively testing on every variation of iOS on every device (which is pretty unrealistic $$$) but I believe Apple has a testing program you can pay for that does just that. However considering you're just playing AV, there shouldn't be much of an incompatibility issue! I'll post the above as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this list:
http://www.expertisemobile.com/2011/10/28/html5-video-and-audio-tags-support-on-mobile-device-real-world-feedback/

In my opinion today's apps don't have to work in very old version of iOS so supporting iOS 4 and newer would be ok.

Go ahead, even if the  tag is not fully supported by older version, it still works!